# How to calculate the covariance matrix of a multivariate normal distribution using maximum likelihood estimation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am wondering the correct way to calculate the covariance matrix found by using Maximum Likelihood Estiamtion. The following equation is the result after having followed algebraic steps:

$\Sigma_{MLE}^*=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu_{MLE}^*)(x_i-\mu_{MLE}^*)^T$

And I interpreted the above equation into matrix form as follows:

$\Sigma_{MLE}^* = \dfrac{1}{n}\begin{bmatrix}X_1-\mu_1^* \\ \\ X_2-\mu_2^*\\ \\ \vdots \\ \\ X_n-\mu_n^*\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X_1-\mu_1^* & X_2-\mu_2^* & \dots &X_n-\mu_n^*\end{bmatrix}$

$= \dfrac{1}{n}\begin{bmatrix}(X_1-\mu_1^*)(X_1-\mu_1^*) & (X_1-\mu_1^*)(X_2-\mu_2^*) & \dots & (X_1-\mu_1^*)(X_n-\mu_n^*) \\ (X_2-\mu_2^*)(X_1-\mu_1^*) & (X_2-\mu_2^*)(X_2-\mu_2^*) & \dots & (X_2-\mu_2^*)(X_n-\mu_n^*) \\ & \vdots \\ (X_n-\mu_n^*)(X_1-\mu_1^*) & (X_n-\mu_n^*)(X_2-\mu_2^*) & \dots & (X_n-\mu_n^*)(X_n-\mu_n^*)\end{bmatrix}$

I wonder if I have understood correctly, hope to hear some advice if I am wrong.

Comment: Your very first equation is already the maximum-likelihood estimator of the population covariance.

Comment: Do you want to prove why your first equation is the MLE estimator? Is this what you're asking?

Comment: If possible, I'd like to look at the proof in detail as long as if I can follow the math. But at least, I'd like to know if I have denoted the matrix form equation correctly for maximum likelihood estimation case.

Comment: Notice that what you are calculating is covariance matrix *using* the maximum likelihood estimate of $\mu$. It does not prove that your estimate is a MLE since you have not proven that it actually maximizes the likelihood! Moreover, you didn't even stated what likelihood you are maximizing (supposedly it's multivariate normal distribution, but it needs to be said explicitly, since there is no such a thing as maximizing *any* likelihood).

Comment: I assume a multivariate normal distribution.